# Convert a equation with fractions into whole numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this equation:

$$\frac{2}{3}a^2-\frac{4}{9}a^2 = 8a$$

So this is a really easy problem, I could just multiply

$$\frac{2}{3}*\frac{3}{3} = \frac{6}{9}$$

Then subtract

$$\frac{6}{9}a^2 - \frac{4}{9}a^2 = \frac{2}{9}a^2=8a$$
$$36a=a^2$$
$$36=a$$

However, I want to solve the equation by getting rid of the fractions right at the beginning:

$$\frac{2}{3}a^2-\frac{4}{9}a^2 = 8a$$

So I thought it'd be much simpler if I could get rid of these fractions by multiplying everything by a single value. Therefore, I thought what value can I multiply 2 and 4 so it gives me a divisible value by 3 and 9? It took me some time but I came up with 9

$$\frac{2}{3}a^2-\frac{4}{9}a^2 = 8a$$
$$9(\frac{2}{3}a^2-\frac{4}{9}a^2) = 9(8a)$$
$$6a^2-9a^2 = 8a$$

My question is if there is an easier way to find this value that when multiplied it eliminates the fractions? It took a few valuable seconds to figure out it was 9, so I was wondering if this process has a name or any rules to find it quicker?

Comment: Here's wikipedia on the lowest common denominator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator

Comment: "Therefore, I thought what value can I multiply 2 and 4 so it gives me a divisible value by 3 and 9?"  The 2 and 4 are irrelevant.  This is simply the same as asking "Therefore, I thought what value can I multiply *two numbers* so it gives me a divisible value by 3 and 9?"...Or ... "what number is divisble by 3 and 9"... which is ... 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:  $\frac ab x + \frac cd x = gy$

Multiple by *both* $b$ and $d$.  Multiplying by $bd$ will *always* eleminate everything.  so $bd\frac abx + bd \frac cd x = adx + bc x = bdgy$.

Ex: $\frac 23 a^2 - \frac 49 a^2 = 8a$

$3*9\frac 23 a^2 -3*9\frac 49 a^2 = 3*9*8a$

$18a^2 - 12a^2 = 216 a$

But notice that was over kill. Every term is a multiple of 3.

Method 2: Do it one term at a time:

$\frac ab x + \frac cd x = gy$

$ ax + \frac {bc}dx = by$

$ dax + bcx = bdy$.

Ex:

$\frac 23 a^2 - \frac 49 a^2 = 8a$

$3\frac 23 a^2 - 3\frac 49a^2 = 2a^2 - \frac 43 a^2 = 3*8a = 24a$

$3*2a^2 - 3\frac 43 a^2 = 6a^2 - 4a^2 = 3*24a = 72a$

Notice in this case you avoided the overkill by factoring out the excessive $3$ as it appeared.  Had you started with $9$ it wouldn't have come up at all.

$\frac 23 a^2 - \frac 49 a^2 = 8a$

$9*\frac 23 a^2 - 9*\frac 49 a^2 = 9*8a$

$3*2a^2 - 4a^2 = 72a$.

Method 3:  The conclusion we can reach. Multiply by the least common multiple.

$\frac ab x + \frac cd x = gy$

$\text{lcm}(bd)\frac ab x + \text{lcm}(bd) \frac cd = \text{lcm}(bd)gy$

$d'a x + b'c x = \text{lcm}(bd) gy$.

Example: $\frac 23 a^2 - \frac 49 a^2 = 8a$.  $3=3$ and $9 = 3^2$ so $\text{lcm}(3,9) = 9$.

$9 \frac 23 a^2 + 9\frac 49 a^2 = 9*8a$

$6a^2 - 4a^2 = 9*8a$.

But notice:  You not only should get rid of the denominaters you should *also* get rid of the common factor two.

Final  $\frac ab x + \frac cd x = \frac gh y$.  Multiply both sides by $\frac {\text{lcm}(b,d,h)}{\gcd(a,c,g)}$

So for $\frac 23 a^2 - \frac 49 a^2 = 8a$.  $\text{lcm}(3,9) = 3$ and $\gcd(2,4,8) = 2$.

So multiply everything by $\frac 92$.

$\frac 92\frac 23 a^2 - \frac 92\frac 29 a^2 = \frac 928a$

$3a^2 - 2a^2 = 36a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$9\left(\frac{2}{3}a^2-\frac{4}{9}a^2\right)=8a\cdot9$$ it's
$$6a^2-4a^2=72a$$ and it's not $6a^2-9a^2=8a$, which you wrote.

The continue is 
$$a^2-36a=0$$ or
$$a(a-18)=0,$$
which gives $a=0$ or $a=18$.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply finding a common denominator to work with. If you have an expression $\frac{n_1}{d_1}+\frac{n_2}{d_2}+...+\frac{n_k}{d_k}$, then you want the denominator to be $\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,...,d_k)$.

This now gives for your expression

$$\frac{\frac{n_1}{d_1}\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,...,d_k)+\frac{n_2}{d_2}\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,...,d_k)+...+\frac{n_k}{d_k}\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,...,d_k)}{\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,...,d_k)}$$

The terms in the numerator are all integers which is what you're after.

---

In your case, the lcm is $9$, so you have

$$\frac{2}{3}a^2-\frac{4}{9}a^2 = 8a$$

$\implies$

$$\frac{1}{9}\left(9\times\frac{2}{3}a^2-9\times\frac{4}{9}a^2\right) = 8a$$

$\implies$

$$\left(6a^2-4a^2\right) = 9\times8a$$

---

(Also, as pointed out, you have a typo on the bottom line)

Answer (score 0):

Just take the least common multiple of all your denominators.